# Search only within certain XML tags within HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working with an French-English dictionary which is an HTML file which uses XML tags to identify the language.

```
<html>
<body>
<p><french>bonjour</french> <english>hello</english></p>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I want users to be able to search text tagged as `<english>` or `<french>` only. So far this is my idea for the Javascript code:

```
function FindFrench () {
   var searchstring = french.getElementById("findInput").value; 
}
```

with HTML

```
<input type="text" id="findInput" value="" size="20" />
<button onclick="FindFrench ();">Find French</button>
```

As you can tell, I am pretty new to Javascript so all feedback is welcomed. If there's an easy way to do this using JQuery then maybe I could do it that way as well.

Comment: HTML already has a mechanism for [specifying language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang), use it instead of writing invalid HTML.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks. This is someone else's file. I've simplified the example. They're using the HTML and CSS to display an XML database which contains these language-specific tags but also others like `<synonym>`, `<example_sentence>` etc. Is there no way to work with such a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with non-html tags as if they were html, even if this is certainly not-recommended. The code below implements simple search, by building a case-insensitive expression to search for the query text in the selected language; and then copies all matching rows into the result area.

It would only need minor changes if you were to replace your `<french>` tags by something more standards-compliant, say `<span class="key french">`; you would then need to update the input to read
`<input name="lang" type="radio" value=".key.french" checked="checked"/>French`.

```js
const query = document.querySelector("#search")
query.onchange = query.oninput = (e) => {
    
    const qselector = document.querySelector("input[name=lang]:checked").value
            
    const matches = document.querySelector("#matches")
    matches.replaceChildren(...["(No results)"])

    const text = query.value
    if (text === "") return
    
    const regex = new RegExp(".*" + text + ".*", "i") // case-insensitive
    

    const results = []
    for (let t of document.querySelectorAll(qselector)) {
        // element t matches query
        if (regex.test(t.textContent)) {
            results.push(t.parentNode.cloneNode(true))
        }   
    }
    if (results.length > 0) matches.replaceChildren(...results)
}
```

```css
french, english { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }
div { margin: 1em; padding: .5em; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<div>
<p><french>Bon jour</french><english>Good day</english></p>
<p><french>Pomme de terre</french><english>Potato</english></p>
<p><french>Voiture</french><english>Car</english></p>
<p><french>Au revoire</french><english>Good bye</english></p>
</div>

<div>
<input id="search" name="search" type="search" placeholder="query"/>
<input name="lang" type="radio" value="french" checked="checked"/>French
<input name="lang" type="radio" value="english"/>English
<div id="matches">
(No results)
</div>
</div>
```